# Can I leverage indexing on a column that has a variable value added to it?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with data like this:

```
# id parent sequence   mz1_monoisotopic 
90   0      SGVNHR     669.34           
93   0      IEEIATDLK  1031.56          
95   1      MDLILDDR   990.49           
100  1      LEVSEELIEK 1188.64
```

My application treats this as a 'base table' from which new tables are generated by adding some value (defined by the user) to the column `mz1_monoisotopic`. For example:

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (mz1_monoisotopic + 55) BETWEEN 1000 and 1002`

Since most of the lookups are done via the `mz1_monoisotopic` column, and many of my tables are millions upon millions of entries, I really need to increase search speed. Is it possible to leveraging indexing in this situation or am I out of luck? I learned about functional indexes, but the problem is that the added value can change.

Additionally, the index itself takes too long to create on a new table, so it almost seems like my only option is a full table search.

Comment: No, an index can't be used here. The index would need to know in advance what the value of `mz1_monoisotopic + 55` is in order to index it, and you indicate that is only known by user input. That means that a query must perform the calculation on every single row to see if the result falls within the specified range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an ordinary index works fine. You don't even need an expression index.

*Behold! The power of algebra!*

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE mz1_monoisotopic BETWEEN 1000 - 55 and 1002 - 55;
```

The value can change from query to query, and the index will still work fine. As long as the expressions on the right side evaluate to constant values, they can be used for an indexed lookup.

Comment: Thank you sir, that is great news for me!